# Creating and updating site columns in MOSS publishing site

Tags: sharepoint, moss, publishing, wspbuilder

I have created a feature, a publishing site, in Visual Studio to MOSS - this feature contains a masterpage, some pages, some site columns etc. I have also created a site collection based on my template.

I have several times updated my mastepage and pages with succes. Now I want to update my site columns, adding some columns, but these changes does not appear in my site collection. If I delete my site collection and create a new the new one gets the correct site columns. What am I missing in my update?

I am using WSPBuilder to build and update my feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy your updated package are you deactivating and reactivating the Feature that provisions the site columns? If you don't, the site columns won't show.

Comment: No, I am not doing anything active to deactivate/activate. What can I do, in my code, to do what i necessary?

Comment: I have tested af bit more - If I go to my site settings and deactives and then activates my feature the site columns gets updated. Is it possible to implement the deactivation/activation to my wsp-package?

Comment: You could script the deployment as Colin suggests or you could use the SharePoint Solution Installer (http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller) to create a setup program that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include this is the wsp, you could however script the deployment of the .wsp and after it has been deployed (i.e. retracted old version, added new version, then deployed to correct web apps) include an

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -url URL -name FEATURENAME
```

and

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -url URL -name FEATURENAME
```

In the deployment script after all the stsadm calls to deploy the solution.

Comment: Tnx - One last question (hopefully); when I add new html-content to my page these appear as soon as I have updated my feature, but if I add site columns these do not appear on my page. What is necessary to do to get these visible too?